# jquery index function repeating content for other elements on the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have multile tables created out of divs (for responsive reasons) on a single page.

I then use jquery to creates a data attribute from the table header which gets added to each table cell. That data attribute is later used in the CSS `content: attr(data-title);` when the screen reaches 720px as a title for each cell in the table.

My problem arises when I have multiple div tables, that the header of the first table is applied to all visible table cells.

**See my example below**

I wondered if there is a way to make the jquery function apply the header content from the first table to each table cell within that individual table only. 
Then the following table would also only receive it's table headers content and so on...

```js
var $table_header = $('.tech-specs header.table-row .table-cell');
var $table_cell = $('.tech-specs div.table-row .table-cell:not(:empty)');
$table_cell.attr('data-title', function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  return $table_header.eq(i).text();
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
header.table-row {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #37bb1f;
}
.table-row > * {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 20px 8px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.table.seven-cells .table-cell {
  width: 25%;
}
/* DEMO STUFF */

div.table-row > *:before {
  content: attr(data-title)" : ";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>This table should add data-title="HEADER 1.X"</h4>
<div class="table tech-specs four-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 1.1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 1.2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 1.3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 1.4</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">CPU</div>
    <div class="table-cell">E3-1230</div>
    <div class="table-cell">E3-1231v3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">E3-1271v3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Cores (threads)</div>
    <div class="table-cell">4 (8)</div>
    <div class="table-cell">4 (8)</div>
    <div class="table-cell">4 (8)</div>
  </div>
</div>


<h4>This table should add data-title="HEADER 2.X"</h4>
<div class="table tech-specs four-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 2.1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 2.2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 2.3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 2.4</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Cisco Powered</div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h4>This table should add data-title="HEADER 3.X"</h4>
<div class="table tech-specs four-cells">
  <header class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 3.1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 3.2</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 3.3</div>
    <div class="table-cell">HEADER 3.4</div>
  </header>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell"><a href="#datacentre">100% owned London DC</a>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always work within the context of the outer parent. `find()` and `closest()` are extremely useful for this sort of situation

```
$('.tech-specs').each(function(){
     var $table = $(this); // instance of table component

    // table instance specific elements     
    var $table_header = $table.find('header.table-row .table-cell');
    var $table_cell = $table.find('div.table-row .table-cell:not(:empty)');

    $table_cell.attr('data-title', function() {
      var i = $(this).index();
      return $table_header.eq(i).text();
    });    
});
```

Comment: Thank you, absolutely perfect.